# Quick access to the numerical integration coordinates and weights?

Tags: acegen

How can one simply access the numerical integration coordinates and weights for a given integration code (e.g. 23) without generating the code itself? Is there some command for it? Something similar to `SMCFEMTopologyData` would be nice, however not for element topology, but rather for the numerical integration code.

Appendix C in "Automation of Finite Element Methods" by Korelc and Wriggers gives these data for most integration codes, but not all cases are covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the Gauss point coordinates and weights of AceFEM are stored in a file "SMSUtility.c", which is located in "C:\Users\$Username\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications\AceFEM\Include\CDriver" or in your global install directory. They are not accessible anywhere in Mathematica.

If you want you could export them in postprocessing and then acces them from `AceFEM` as:

```
position =  Position[SMTDomains[[1, 23]], #][[1, 1]] & /@ {"Xg", "Yg", "wg"}
SMTData[1, "SPP"][[1, ;; , position]]
```

For this to work you have to export `"Xg"`, `"Yg"` and  `"wg"`in postprocessing first!

Another option is to write a task called e.g. "IntegrationPoint" (see "USER DEFINED TASKS" chapter in help for details). 
Task would be defined as:

```
SMSTemplate[...,"SMSCharSwitch" -> {"IntegrationPoint"},...]; 

 ...

SMSStandardModule["Tasks"];
task \[RightTee] SMSInteger[Task$$];
ng\[RightTee]SMSInteger[es$$["id", "NoIntPoints"]];
SMSSwitch[task
    , -1, SMSExport[{1, 0, 0, 0, 3*ng}, TasksData$$]
];

SMSSwitch[task
    , 1, SMSDo[
      Table[SMSExport[SMSReal[es$$["IntPoints", i, Ig]],RealOutput$$[3*(Ig - 1) + i]], {i, 3}];
      , {Ig, 1, ng}
      ]
];
```

Which will then be called in AceFEM as `SMTTask["IntegrationPoint","Element"->1]`